# What vocabulary am I missing when talking about taking an interval and making it into a vector?

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology

I have a spacial variable, let's say $X \in [0,1]$. For an algorithm I want to use, I need to make break this interval into finite pieces, that is select a grid from this interval, such as $x=[0,.2,.4,.6,.8,1]$. I'm trying to describe this process, but I feel I am lacking a certain (or a few) word(s) to explain this clearly.

What is it called when you take an interval and make it into a vector? What if you want to make that vector have more or fewer points (more or less detail), is there a term to describe that?

Edit: From the comments it seems my question isn't clear enough. I'm trying to say I take smaller and smaller refinements of the interval [0,1] (in my example I have a refinement with step size .2, then maybe I could take one with size .1, etc.), but I thought maybe there was a better way to describe that.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but maybe a partition? I'm not seeing where there are any vectors.

Comment: Maybe "vector" in the computer-programming sense of "list of numbers"?

Comment: If I understand your first question, in a 1D context, the concept of vector is equivalent to a **signed length**. For your second question, I don't see the interest to describe a sequence of points in terms of vecotrs...

Comment: @ElliotG x is a vector ( an ordered list of numbers), an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n=6$ in my example) .

Comment: If you are talking about partitions, then "refinement" is the right word.  Considering the partition as a collection of disjoint subintervals whose union is the whole interval, then the partition $P_1$ is said to a refinement of $P_2$ if every interval in $P_1$ is a subset of some interval in $P_2$.

Comment: "Sampling density" or "sampling frequency" comes to mind, as what you really want to do is to represent continuous or smooth function by a sufficiently detailed function value table.